# How to add in a class click event vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

I have a class (shape). I want to create an object of myclass (shape) with mouse click event on a form at runtime.
I add it but click event not work. basically : ClickEvent not work.

I saw it in C# but I can not convert it to vb.net.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Shape
    Inherits Control
    Public x1 As Integer
    Public x2 As Integer
    Public y1 As Integer
    Public y2 As Integer
    Public Sub New(x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, ByRef g As Graphics)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.x1 = x1 : Me.x2 = x2 : Me.y1 = y1 : Me.y2 = y2
        draw(g)
        AddHandler Me.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf ClickEvent)
    End Sub
    Public Sub draw(ByRef egraphics As Graphics)
        Dim _mybrush As Brush ' brush to fill vertex
        _mybrush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.White)
        Dim _mypen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5) ' make pen to draw
        _mypen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
        egraphics.FillRectangle(_mybrush, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
        egraphics.DrawRectangle(_mypen, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
    End Sub
    Private Sub ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles MyBase.Click
        MsgBox("Hi")
    End Sub
End Class
```

in form1 I add this code.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer
    Dim WithEvents s As Shape

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        x1 = e.X
        y1 = e.Y
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        s = New Shape(x1, y1, e.X, e.Y, Me.CreateGraphics)
        Me.Controls.Add(s)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're drawing the rectangle through graphics, but that drawing is independant to the control location. The class should resemble the following, with the Top, Left, Height and Width properties set. Also, the control itself doesn't need to implement the click event, as this is inherited from the "Control".

Shape Class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Shape
    Inherits Control
    Public x1 As Integer
    Public x2 As Integer
    Public y1 As Integer
    Public y2 As Integer
    Public Sub New(x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, ByRef g As Graphics)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.x1 = x1 : Me.x2 = x2 : Me.y1 = y1 : Me.y2 = y2
        draw(g)

        Me.Left = x1
        Me.Top = y1
        Me.Width = x2 - x1
        Me.Height = y2 - y1

    End Sub
    Public Sub draw(ByRef egraphics As Graphics)
        Dim _mybrush As Brush ' brush to fill vertex
        _mybrush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.White)
        Dim _mypen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5) ' make pen to draw
        _mypen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
        egraphics.FillRectangle(_mybrush, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
        egraphics.DrawRectangle(_mypen, New Rectangle(x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1))) ' dont change between this line and next line if change you can not to see border
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the form code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer
    Dim WithEvents s As Shape

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        x1 = e.X
        y1 = e.Y
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        s = New Shape(x1, y1, e.X, e.Y, Me.CreateGraphics)
        Me.Controls.Add(s)
    End Sub

    Public Sub clickevt(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles s.Click
        MsgBox("Hi")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.